typeerror: callback is not a function - mocha
I am new to typescript and I have written testcases for databaseHelper class to insert or update date. I am getting callback is not a function error. I am making one call to check if agency exists in DB and one call to update Agent in DB. These are the two calls I am making in my actual class. Is the way I am stubbing wrong for multiple calls?
Here is my databaseHelper class-
const knex = startKnex();


export const insertOrUpdateAgent = async (agentData: UpdateEventData) => {
  const trx = await knex.transaction();

  try {
    // Check if the agency exists
    const agencyExists = await trx('agency')
      .select('agency_id')
      .where('agency_id', agentData.agencyId)
      .first();

    // If the agency does not exist, skip the insert/update
    if (!agencyExists) {
      console.log(`Agency ID ${agentData.agencyId} does not exist. Skipping agent insert/update.`);
      await trx.rollback();
      return "Agency does not exist";
    }

    // If the agency exists, insert or update the agent record
    await trx('agent')
      .insert({
        agent_id: agentData.agentId,
        agency_id: agentData.agencyId,
        updated_by: 'system'
      })
      .onConflict('agent_id')
      .merge();

    await trx.commit();
    return "success";

  } catch (error) {
    await trx.rollback();
    console.error('Transaction failed:', error);
    throw new Error("Transaction failed: " + error.message);
  }
};

Here is my test class-
describe('insertOrUpdateAgent', () => {
  let testModule: any;
  let knexStub: any;
  let trxStub: any;
  let rollbackStub: any;
  let commitStub: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // Create transaction stub
    rollbackStub = sinon.stub();
    commitStub = sinon.stub();

    // Creating a mock for the transaction object
    trxStub = {
      rollback: rollbackStub,
      commit: commitStub,
      select: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      where: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      first: sinon.stub(),
      insert: sinon.stub(),
      onConflict: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      merge: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
    };

    // Mock for knex that returns our transaction stub
    knexStub = {
      transaction: sinon.stub().callsFake(async (callback) => {
       
        const trx = {
          rollback: rollbackStub,
          commit: commitStub,
          select: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
          where: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
          first: sinon.stub(),
          insert: sinon.stub(),
          onConflict: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
          merge: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        };
        return await callback(trx); 
      }),
    };

    testModule = proxyquire('../../src/helpers/databaseHelper', {
      '../../src/helpers/knexHelper': {
        startKnex: () => knexStub,
      },
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  // Test case 1: Agency exists, insert or update the agent
  it.only('should insert or update the agent when agency exists', async () => {
    const agentData: UpdateEventData = {
      agentId: '123',
      agencyId: '456',
    };

    // Stubbing for agency exists
    trxStub.first.resolves({ agency_id: '456' });
    trxStub.insert.resolves(); // Resolving insert

    const result = await testModule.insertOrUpdateAgent(agentData);

    expect(trxStub.first).to.have.been.calledOnce; // Check if agency was checked
    expect(trxStub.insert).to.have.been.calledOnce; // Check if insert was called
    expect(trxStub.insert).to.have.been.calledWith({
      agent_id: agentData.agentId,
      agency_id: agentData.agencyId,
      updated_by: 'system',
    });
    expect(commitStub).to.have.been.calledOnce; // Check if commit was called
    expect(result).to.equal('success'); // Check the returned value
  });

This is the complete error :
 TypeError: callback is not a function
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests\helpers\databaseHelper.ts:40:17)
      at Object.invoke (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\behavior.js:177:32)
      at Object.functionStub (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\stub.js:44:43)
      at Function.invoke (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\proxy-invoke.js:53:47)
      at Object.functionStub [as transaction] (node_modules\sinon\lib\sinon\proxy.js:265:26)
      at Object.insertOrUpdateAgent (src\helpers\databaseHelper.ts:9:26)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests\helpers\databaseHelper.ts:83:37)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:483:21)

